# Integration testing with Karma

Tags: javascript, html, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Until now, I've done all my testing with just Jasmine and jQuery to automate the browser. I am starting to explore Karma but it seems to be set up only for unit tests that involve loading HTML fragments as test fixtures and I find no way to load a whole web page. Am I missing something or is this simply the wrong tool for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

From the [karma FAQ's](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/faq.html) section:

> **Can I use Karma to do end to end testing?**
>
> Karma has primarily been designed for low level (unit) testing. If it's an AngularJS app, you can use Karma with the karma-ng-scenario plugin. However, we recommend Protractor for high-level testing.

Typically, loading a whole web page goes beyond the scope of single units of code: you need to spin up a browser, load the page and make your actions and assertions. End-to-end testing frameworks like [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/), [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) or [Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) might be more suitable for this specific case.

Comment: Thank you, Mauri.  That's what I needed to know.  I am looking into Webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

You can do integration testing using the following toolchain:

**Karma ➔ Mocha ➔ Mocha-CasperJS ➔ CasperJS**.

Check out the [mocha-casperjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-casperjs) package.